# Storing contents of textarea with line breaks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I'm trying to store the contents of a textarea into localStorage including line breaks.

```
<textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="delivery-address-input" id="delivery-address-input" required></textarea>
```

Imagine the contents of the text area are:

```
1234 Smith Street
Dunedin
New Zealand
```

`$('#delivery-address-input').val()` returns the contents including the linebreaks.

But when I try:

`localStorage.setItem("contact-address", $('#delivery-address-input').val();`

And check the contents:

`localStorage.getItem("contact-address")`

The linebreaks are all truncated

1234Smith StreetDunedinNew Zealand

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var val = $('#delivery-address-input').val().replace(/\n\r?/g, '<br/>');
localStorage.setItem("contact-address", val);
```

textarea line breaks are like this `\n\r` and html is `<br/>` so replace textarea line breaks to html ones .